# How to apply a single Search View on multiple Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am working on a Language translator project. In which I am using multiple Fragments with TabLayout and `Viewpager`. I am also using a `RecyclerView` for displaying Lists. Each Fragment has its own instance of RecyclerViewAdapter Class. But I want to apply a search View in the action as well. In which I want to filter results from all the fragments. But it's not working. If you more details about my project just let me know.

Here my `MainActivity`

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.ClothesFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.ColorFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.EatingOutFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.FamilyFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.GreetingFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Fragments.NumberFragment;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.Adapters.PagerAdpater;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mTabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mViewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        PagerAdpater adpater=new PagerAdpater(getSupportFragmentManager());

        adpater.addFragment(new GreetingFragment(),"Greeting");
        adpater.addFragment(new NumberFragment(),"Numbers");
        adpater.addFragment(new EatingOutFragment(),"Eating Out");
        adpater.addFragment(new ColorFragment(),"Colors");
        adpater.addFragment(new ClothesFragment(),"Clothes");
        adpater.addFragment(new FamilyFragment(),"Family");

        mViewPager.setAdapter(adpater);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_search_menu,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Type here to search");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                //Dont Know what to do now??
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Here My RecyclerView Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.fidu.learnchinese.R;
import com.fidu.learnchinese.models.ChineseLanguage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdpater.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<ChineseLanguage> mChineseLanguages;
    private List<ChineseLanguage> mChineseLanguagesFull;
    private Context mContext;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    public RecyclerViewAdpater(List<ChineseLanguage> chineseLanguages, Context context) {
        mChineseLanguages = chineseLanguages;
        mChineseLanguagesFull=new ArrayList<>(mChineseLanguages);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtEnglishWord.setText(mChineseLanguages.get(position).getEnglishAlphabet());
        holder.txtChineseWord.setText(mChineseLanguages.get(position).getChineseAlphabet());
        holder.txtPronunciation.setText(mChineseLanguages.get(position).getPronounciation());

        holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                releasaMedia();
                mMediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(mContext,mChineseLanguages.get(position).getSound());
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        releasaMedia();
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    private void releasaMedia(){
        if (mMediaPlayer!=null){
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }
        mMediaPlayer=null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mChineseLanguages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter filter=new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<ChineseLanguage> filteredList=new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint.toString().isEmpty()){
                filteredList.addAll(mChineseLanguagesFull);
            }else {
                for(ChineseLanguage item: mChineseLanguagesFull){
                    if (item.getEnglishAlphabet().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim())){
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values=filteredList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
          mChineseLanguages.clear();
          mChineseLanguages.addAll((Collection<? extends ChineseLanguage>) results.values);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        };


        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtEnglishWord,txtChineseWord,txtPronunciation;
        ImageButton btnPlay;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtEnglishWord=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtEnglishWord);
            txtChineseWord=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtChineseWord);
            txtPronunciation=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPronunciation);
            btnPlay=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a Fragment for better understanding

```
 public class ClothesFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewClothes;
    private List<ChineseLanguage> mClothes;

    public ClothesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mClothes=new ArrayList<>();
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Wear","穿","chuān",R.raw.clothes_wear));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Put On","穿","chuān",R.raw.clothes_put_on));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Take On","脱下","tuō xià",R.raw.clothes_take_off));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Clothes","衣服","yī fú",R.raw.clothes_clothes));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Trousers","裤子","kù zi",R.raw.clothes_trousers));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Shirt","衬衫","chèn shān",R.raw.clothes_shirt));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("T-shirt","衬衣","chèn yī",R.raw.clothes_t_shirt));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Dress","连衣裙","lián yī qún",R.raw.clothes_dress));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Pair of Socks","袜子","wà zi",R.raw.clothes_pair_of_socks));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Pair of Shoes","鞋子","xié zi",R.raw.clothes_pair_of_shoes));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Sweatshirt","运动衫","yùn dòng shān",R.raw.clothes_sweatshirt));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Jacket","夹克","jiá kè",R.raw.clothes_jacket));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Skirt","裙子","qún zi",R.raw.clothes_skirt));
        mClothes.add(new ChineseLanguage("Suit","套装","tào zhuāng",R.raw.clothes_suit));


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clothes, container, false);
        mRecyclerViewClothes=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewClothes);
        mRecyclerViewClothes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        RecyclerViewAdpater adpater=new RecyclerViewAdpater(mClothes,getActivity());
        mRecyclerViewClothes.setAdapter(adpater);
        return view;
    }

}
```

**Now what I want is. When I enter a text in search view Bar. It should be filtered from all fragments**

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use Realm DataBase and get query on this and show result as a listview.

Or

Use data binding and bind all items of your fragments.

update me

Comment: Is the answer relevant to question?

Comment: he want do a job, i push him to 2 ways can do it.it's not helpful?